# Laravel 5 eloquent could not save a one to many related model

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

The application have the models:
NotificationParent.php

```
class NotificationParent extends Model{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'NotificationParent';
    protected $primaryKey = 'notificationparent_id';
    protected $fillable = ['category', 'description'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Notification', 'notificationparent_id', 'notification_id');
   }
```

}

Notification.php

```
class Notification extends Model{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'Notification';
    protected $primaryKey = 'notification_id';
    protected $fillable = ['notificationparent_id', 'title', 'description', 'link'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


    public function notificationParent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\NotificationParent', 'notification_id', 'notificationparent_id');
    }
}
```

I could not save a notification with following code:

```
$notification = new Notification(['title' => 'access denied', 'description' => 'access denied for user one' , 'link' => 'http----']);
$notificationParent = NotificationParent::where('category', '=', 'admin')->first();
$notificationParent->notifications()->save($notification);
```

even though $notificationParent is not null it gives error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'notificationparent_id', table 'five.dbo.Notification'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (SQL: insert into [Notification] ([title], [description], [link], [notificationparent_id], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (access denied, access denied for user one, http---, , 2015-04-21 16:02:57.000, 2015-04-21 16:02:57.000))
```

Comment: Try changing `notificationParent()` to `return $this->belongsTo()` rather than `$this->hasOne()`

Comment: Changed notificationParent() to return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Utility\NotificationParent', 'notificationparent_id', 'notification_id'); Still error says 'notificationparent_id' is null.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble.I have Mistakenly used wrong 'local_key' in hasMany().Thanks for correcting inverse relation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hasOne is used for a one to one relationship.
The inverse of hasMany is belongsTo

Comment: Changed notificationParent() to return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Utility\NotificationParent', 'notificationparent_id', 'notification_id'); Still give same error 'notificationparent_id' is null.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble.I have Mistakenly used wrong 'local_key' in hasMany().Thanks for correcting inverse relation issue.